# Windows command to hibernate and resume

Tags: windows, hibernate, prompt

I would like to know if there is a way to make a Windows prompt script that hibernates the PC and after one hour resumes the activity?

Any tip will be very helpful,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch file and add /h to hibernate and /f to force close running programs.

```
shutdown /h /f
```

As for waking up the PC after hibernating go to Start - Control Panel - Power Options and then Change when the computer sleeps. From there click Change advanced power settings; and allow wake timers.

Comment: To wake the PC, you can use a Scheduled Task. See http://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/

Comment: Is there a way to wake up automatically?